# Does permission protectionLevel="signature" absolutely secure?

Tags: android, android-manifest, broadcast, android-broadcast

I need to send secure data between my applications by sending broadcast with permission:

```
 <permission android:name="my.custom.PERMISSION"     
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

 sendBroadcast(intent,"my.custom.PERMISSION");
```

I wanna be sure that another app (including root devices and devices from non popular vendors) will not have access to intent sent this way.

Comment: non root, yes. root, no.

Comment: @Blundell, What is no ?, Not OP but confused with comment.

Comment: sorry I meant: for non rooted devices yes its _probably_ secure. For non-rooted its definetely not secure